Does Cmak still connects to zookeeper and not brokers? Can someone help me with the steps/configuration for cmak to connect to SSL zookeeper?
I am having cmak in our environment. Can someone help me with the steps or configuration to connect cmak to SSL zookeeper
Tried creating a client SSL for zookeeper and add the zk client configuration. Didn't work. Can someone help on this
